# WMLibrary.dll or one of it dependencies requires later version of the .net framework

Tags: c#, .net

I exported a .exe file  to c# using .net refelector and added all the references but one of the reference is WMLibrary and when I tried to add it comes up with this error  all the reference are version 2.0 and one of its dependencies system.core is having version=3.5 how can I add this dll file by changing system.core  to 2.0 and compile it any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What framework version is the project targeting?

Comment: check -->http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: targeting framework 2.0

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, System.Core is not supported directly by Framework 2.0.